# How to style Google app invites screen

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

We have implemented Google App Invites on Android. It's working but doesn't look as an integrated part: the gray status bar, the blue toolbar and the default font just don't fit with our app. And the blue toolbar doesn't look like a native part of the OS either.

How can we can set the status bar color, toolbar color and the font?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently the invite page cannot be customized. However, the invitation can be fully customize with HTML starting with Google Play Services 8.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know even though it's doesn't really help us. Most likely we're not going to use it. It's coupled too closely to Google accounts, excludes Facebook and we couldn't get it running on iOS (seems to be in conflict with either Google Maps, Google Ads SDK or Google Analytics).

Comment: Now that we have Play Services 8.4.0, how do we customize with HTML? Here's my question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664756/appinvites-how-to-customize-with-html

Comment: As far as I understand, the UI of the sender is not customizable. Jim is referring to the invitation that the recipient gets.

Comment: And if that's true, the question is still how...?

Comment: So what with the material design thing if it takes someone out of the flow of the app?

Comment: Also you should make option to use it as a card or dialog and not the whole page. And the theme should be automatically the same as the calling application theme.