# Android AppInvites API - How to customize with HTML

Tags: android, styles, google-app-invites

I've just implemented `App Invites` but the intent that starts has a `status bar` color different than the one I've set for my activities.

Now according to this answer, they are now customizable with `HTML` but I cannot find documentation on how to do so... 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165179/4543112

**EDIT**: Is it just a rumor or does anyone have an idea if this is really achievable and **how**?

Comment: As far as I understand, the UI of the sender is not customizable. In http://stackoverflow.com/a/35165179/4543112, Jim refers to the invitation that the recipient gets.

Comment: He said the invitation can be customized but not the app invite dialog

Comment: How how how is the question, i know what he said xD